how to show ratios in power bi visuals
I am trying to build a dash board in power bi and I have a table visual with below columns.
I want to include this ratio column to know the ratio of devices to user by country. But facing challenge in calculating ratio. When I try to access the table visual column names power bi only shows me options to pick from the dataset table columns. How can I access table visual columns?
What I have:



Country
No of devices
no of users




America
5
5


Korea
21
12


Hong Kong
80
72



I want to have below:



Country
No of devices
no of users
Ratio of device to user ratio




America
5
5
0


Korea
21
12
1.75


Hong Kong
80
72
1.11




pls provide some sample data and expected output.

What I have is a table but I'm not able to insert table here in table format. Below is what I have in table visual:                                                                                                                        Country | Mobile | users                                                                                                                        America | 80        |    59                                                                                           Korea     | 165      | 122

you can use markdown table https://tabletomarkdown.com/. Otherwise, I can't provide the solution.

Thanks for the link but what ever I do it shows like a mark down table while editing once I save it goes back to plan paragraph formatting. It is not showing up as table after I save the edit. :( I have tried to add the what I have and what I want tables in the original post above due to length constraints in comment section.

pls try this
ratio=Divide( count([devices],count[users])


Please explain how this would solve the issu

Thanks for the reply. I tried above formula but the column names given in above table are from 'table visual' and If I try to put the table visual column names in this formula it is not able to recognise them. It underlines the column name in red and says that [Cannot find name '[No of Users]' for both columns.

so pls provide some sample data(not table visual)

okay, so does that mean that we cannot access table visual columns and calculate? On the other hand can I use measure to calculate the ratio and display in table visual. Another problem with using columns from the main dataset is that users column is a string col with user names. I have created a table visual with count of users, hence I thought it was easy to use column from the table visual. My goal is to show this ratio in a bar/column graph. Hence doing all these calculations.

We can access table visual columns and calculate. The problem is that you can't generate the result with the coding I provided. Did you use measure to display the count? In fact, I think we just need to divide those two columns.

Yep, I used the code given by you but since those column names were from table visual it is not recognising the column names.  [Cannot find name '[No of Users]' , getting this even before I run the code.
